# Cannot import name 'app' with uWSGI and NGINX

Tags: python, flask, uwsgi, wsgi

I'm trying to get a Flask site onto NGINX, and I'm having an issue getting the Flask server online.

I've followed [this](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-serve-flask-applications-with-uswgi-and-nginx-on-ubuntu-18-04#step-4-%E2%80%94-configuring-uwsgi) DigitalOcean tutorial, and I've used multiple SO questions as well, and nothing has helped.
If I run `uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:8080 --protocol=http --module wsgi --callable app`, 
the only helpful traceback I can get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from app import app
ImportError: cannot import name 'app'
unable to load app 0 (mountpoint='') (callable not found or import error)
```

My directory structure looks like this:

```
Xerix/
  __pycache__/
  app/
    __init.py__
    static
    templates
    xerix.db
  cert/
    xerix_me.crt
  flask/ (virtualenv)
  wsgi.py
  xerix.ini
```

If I run `journalctl -u xerix`, I get:

```
Nov 29 17:43:18 xerix systemd[1]: Started uWSGI instance to serve xerix.
Nov 29 17:43:18 xerix systemd[1]: xerix.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=203/EXEC
Nov 29 17:43:18 xerix systemd[1]: xerix.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

( That is the most recent log )

How do I fix this, and What do I do?

Any and all help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are contents of `app/__init__.py`?

Comment: @KamilNiski the whole app / website

Comment: what are the contents of `xerix.ini` and your nginx server block?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem has nothing to do with nginx. You have to tell uwsgi where to find your library and dependencies. Create an `myapp.wsgi` file with the following content under Xerix folder:

```
# myapp.wsgi
from app import app as application
```

Save it and run uwsgi like this:

```
uwsgi --http :8080 --wsgi-file myapp.wsgi --chdir /path/to/Xerix/ --pythonpath flask/python-3.7.0/lib/python3.7/site-packages
```

You might need to tweak the path a bit according to your python version.

Comment: Got `ImportError: cannot import name 'app'` when I ran that command. All that is in `myapp.wsgi` is what you provided.

Comment: What's the output of running `python -c 'from app import app'` inside Xerix folder?